# Product $\sigma$-algebra vs Cartesion product of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory

Given two measurable spaces $(X,\mathcal{X})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{Y})$, I know that $\mathcal{X} \boxtimes \mathcal{Y}$ is not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra (see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31000/cartesian-product-of-two-sigma-algebras-is-generally-not-a-sigma-algebra)). Here, $\mathcal{X} \boxtimes \mathcal{Y} := \{ A \times B \mid A \in \mathcal{X}, B \in \mathcal{Y} \}$.

As a $\sigma$-algebra on $X \times Y$, one usually uses the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{X} \boxtimes \mathcal{Y}$, denoted $\sigma(\mathcal{X} \boxtimes \mathcal{Y})$.

Intuitively, my question is: **What is the difference between $\mathcal{X} \boxtimes \mathcal{Y}$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{X} \boxtimes \mathcal{Y})$?**

I know that $\mathcal{X} \boxtimes \mathcal{Y} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{X} \boxtimes \mathcal{Y})$, and that in general, $\mathcal{X} \boxtimes \mathcal{Y} \neq \sigma(\mathcal{X} \boxtimes \mathcal{Y})$. But which elements does $\sigma(\cdot)$ add?
Concretely, does the following hold maybe?

$$
\sigma(\mathcal{X} \boxtimes \mathcal{Y}) = \left\{ \bigcup_{i=1} S_i \mid S_i \in \mathcal{X} \boxtimes \mathcal{Y} \right\}
$$

This equality excludes the usual counterexamples, e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/31002/437564).

Comment: No -- Try $X=Y=\mathbb R$, $\mathcal X=\mathcal Y=\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $A=\{(x,x)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ the diagonal.

Comment: Hmm, right. Thanks!