# The set of measurable rectangles is an algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading section *7.1 The Product Measure Theorem* from [this](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ebeforres/PMath451/Course_Notes/Chapter7.pdf) lecture note.

---

**Problem 7.1.1.** Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B})$ be measurable spaces. Is there a natural way to define a measure on the space $X \times Y$ which reflects the structure of the original measure space?

**Definition 7.1.2.** Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B})$ be measurable spaces. A measurable rectangle is a set of the form $A \times B$, where $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$. Let $Z=X \times Y$ and
$$
\mathcal{Z}_0=\left\{\coprod_{i=1}^n A_i \times B_i \mid A_i \in \mathcal{A}, B_i \in \mathcal{B}\right\}.
$$

**Lemma 7.1.3.** $\mathcal{Z}_0$ is an algebra in $\mathcal{P}(Z)$.

---

**My understanding** It seems from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4551911/1019043) answer that $\mathcal{Z}_0$ is not generally an algebra and thus *Lemma 7.1.3.* is not correct. That's why the [construction](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Earinaldo/Teaching/36752/S18/Scribed_Lectures/Feb20.pdf) of product measure is usually not by [Hahn–Kolmogorov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem#Introductory_statement).

> Could you confirm if my understanding is fine?

---

**Update** Below is a [direct construction](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Earinaldo/Teaching/36752/S18/Scribed_Lectures/Feb20.pdf) of product measure I have found.

**Theorem 7.9** (Product measure) Let $\left(\Omega_1, \mathcal{F}_1, \mu_1\right)$ and $\left(\Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_2, \mu_2\right)$ be two measurable spaces where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are $\sigma$-finite measures. There exists a unique measure $\mu$ on $\left(\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2\right)$ that satisfies $\mu\left(A_1 \times\right.$ $\left.A_2\right)=\mu_1\left(A_1\right) \mu_2\left(A_2\right)$ for all $A_1 \in \mathcal{F}_1$ and $A_2 \in \mathcal{F}_2$. This measure is called the product measure, written as $\mu=\mu_1 \times \mu_2$.

**Proof**

1. Uniqueness:

First we show that any such measure must be $\sigma$-finite. Since $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are $\sigma$-finite there exist $\left\{A_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in \mathcal{F}_1$ and $\left\{B_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in F_2$ such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n=\Omega_1, \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n=\Omega_2, \mu_1\left(A_n\right)$ and $\mu_2\left(B_n\right)$ are finite for all $n$. Consider $\bigcup_{(i, j) \in \mathbb{N}^2} A_i \times B_j$. For and $\left(\omega_1, \omega_2\right) \in \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ there exists $i, j$ such that $\omega_1 \in A_i$ and $\omega_2 \in B_j$, which means $\left(\omega_1, \omega_2\right) \in A_i \times b_j$. Hence $\bigcup_{(i, j) \in \mathbb{N}^2} A_i \times B_j=\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$. For any $(i, j) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ we have $\mu\left(A_i \times B_j\right)=$ $\mu_1\left(A_i\right) \mu_2\left(B_j\right)<\infty$. Since $\mathbb{N}^2$ is a countable set we can conclude that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Suppose there are two measures $\mu$ and $\mu^{\prime}$ satisfying the condition in the theorem. Recall that the collection of measurable rectangles $\left\{A_1 \times A_2: A_1 \in \mathcal{F}_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{F}_2\right\}$ is a $\pi$-system. $\mu$ and $\mu^{\prime}$ are both $\sigma$-finite and agree on this $\pi$-system. By Uniqueness theorem they agree on the generated $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2$, i.e., $\mu=\mu^{\prime}$, which means such measure must be unique.

2. Existence:

For any $B \in \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2$ let $\mu(B)=\int_{\Omega_1} \mu_2\left(B_{\omega_1}\right) d \mu_1\left(\omega_1\right)$ where $B_{\omega_1}=\left\{\omega_2 \in \Omega_2:\left(\omega_1, \omega_2\right) \in \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2\right\}$ as introduced previously. Then $\mu$ is a measure.
For any $A_1 \in \mathcal{F}_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{F}_2$,
$$
\mu\left(A_1 \times A_2\right)=\int_{\Omega_1} \mu_2\left(\left(A_1 \times A_2\right)_{\omega_1}\right) d \mu_1\left(\omega_1\right)=\int_{\Omega_1} \mathbb{1}_{A_1} \mu_2\left(A_2\right) d \mu_1\left(\omega_1\right)=\mu_2\left(A_2\right) \int_{\Omega_1} \mathbb{1}_{A_1} d \mu_1\left(\omega_1\right)=\mu_1\left(A_1\right) \mu_2\left(A_2\right)
$$

Hence such measure exists.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation of 7.1.2. What is that operator?

Comment: @Snoop which notation are you referring to?

Comment: The $\coprod$ operator in the context of 7.1.2.

Comment: @Snoop It seems from the sentence *"Define $\pi_0$ on $\mathcal{Z}_0$ by $\pi_0\left(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i \times B_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n \mu\left(A_i\right) \lambda\left(B_i\right)$"* from *Theorem 7.1.4* that $\coprod_{i=1}^n A_i \times B_i$ means $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \times B_i$. It's my fault that I did not read the lecture carefully...

Comment: We use $\coprod$ for a **disjoint union**.  That is, a union where the terms are pairwise disjoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Snoop It seems from *Theorem 7.1.4* that $\coprod_{i=1}^n A_i \times B_i$ in *Definition 7.1.2.* means $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \times B_i$. Then my above understanding is not correct.

---

**Theorem 7.1.4** [Product Measure Theorem]. Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B}, \lambda)$ be measure spaces. Then there exists a measure $\pi$ on $(X \times Y, \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B})$ such that $\pi(A \times B)=\mu(A) \lambda(B)$. Moreover, if $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are $\sigma$-finite, then $\pi$ is unique and $\sigma$-finite.
In the case where $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are $\sigma$-finite, we denote the uniquely obtained measure by
$$
\pi=\mu \times \lambda
$$
and call the measure the product of $\mu$ and $\lambda$.

**Proof.** Suppose that $A \times B$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \times B_i$, where each of the measurable rectangles $A_i \times B_i$ are disjoint. Then
$$
\chi_A(x) \chi_B(y)=\chi_{A \times B}(x, y)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \chi_{A_i}(x) \chi_{B_i}(y)
$$
for all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$. Fix $x$ and integrate with respect to $\lambda$. By MCT,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_Y \chi_{A \times B}(x, y) d \lambda(y) & =\int_Y \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \chi_{A_i}(x) \chi_{B_i}(y) d \lambda(y) \\
\int_Y \chi_A(x) \chi_B(y) d \lambda(y) & =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \chi_{A_i}(x) \int_Y \chi_{B_i}(y) d \lambda(y) \\
\chi_A(x) \lambda(B) & =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \chi_{A_i}(x) \lambda\left(B_i\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Further integrating with respect to $\mu$ yields (again by MCT)
$$
\mu(A) \lambda(B)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu\left(A_i\right) \lambda\left(B_i\right) \quad(*).
$$

**Define $\pi_0$ on $\mathcal{Z}_0$ by $\pi_0\left(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i \times B_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n \mu\left(A_i\right) \lambda\left(B_i\right)$**. Then $\pi_0$ is a measure on $\mathcal{Z}$ by $(*)$ (the only nontrivial issue to check was countable additivity). Caratheodory's Extension Theorem gives us a measure $\pi$ defined on at least $\mathcal{Z}$ that extends $\pi_0$. If $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are $\sigma$-finite, then $\pi_0$ is $\sigma$-finite, so Hahn's Extension Theorem tells us that $\pi$ is unique.